# How to automatically propagate the XMLNS attribute from on XSL template to another

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I'm looking for a way to have the XMLNS attribute propagate automatically from one XSL Template to another so I don't have to redeclare it each time.

Here's my situation. I'm trying to transform an XML file into an XHTML file using a XSLT file. My XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" encoding="UTF-8" href="car.xslt" version="1.0"?>
<vehicle>
  <car>
    <make>Honda</make>
    <color>blue</color>
  </car>
  <car>
    <make>Saab</make>
    <color>red</color>
  </car>
</vehicle>
```

My XSLT file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
  <table cellpadding="5" border="1">
    <tr><td>make</td><td>color</td></tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="car">
    <tr xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <td><xsl:value-of select="make"/></td><td><xsl:value-of select="color"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the XSLT file, I would like to just be able to say:

```
<xsl:template match="car">
    <tr>
```

without having to redeclare the XMLNS. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make XHTML the default namespace in the stylesheet; it then applies to every template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
  version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to redeclare `xmlns` in the example you have given. When an non-qualified QName (i.e. one without a prefix, like `car`) is used in XPath, it is treated as an element in *empty* namespace, regardless of whether you have `xmlns="..."` in scope or not. So you can stick `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` on your `<xsl:template>` element, and `car` won't change its meaning in XPath.