# Can XSLT 1.0 use a variable on the xmlns attribute in a select clause?

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, namespaces, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to understand if it is possible for an XSLT **1.0** script to be made reusable with xml files with similar *but not equal* schemas which share the same namespace prefix.

The variable `ns-uri` contains the desired namespace but it seems XSLT 1.0 does not recognizes this usage in `xmlns:emp='$ns-uri'` although using the same attribute with a string with a namespace works.

I do not want to follow the suggestion of using the construction `*[name()='emp:department']` as this renders the xslt completely unreadable.

Any more suggestions or is this a final limitation on XSLT 1.0?

Note: as I'm using prefixes, the answers in [How to automatically propagate the XMLNS attribute from on XSL template to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534670/how-to-automatically-propagate-the-xmlns-attribute-from-on-xsl-template-to-anoth) do not apply.

Thank You.

---

#### Sample code

The following **does not** work:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:param name="ns-uri" select="/child::*[1]/namespace-uri()"/>

    <xsl:template match="emp:employee" xmlns:emp="http://www.example.com/ns/employee/2006">
        First Name "<xsl:value-of select="emp:first" xmlns:emp="http://www.example.com/ns/employee/2006"/>"
        Last Name  "<xsl:value-of select="emp:last"  xmlns:emp='$ns-uri'/>"
        Department "<xsl:value-of select="*[name()='emp:department']"/>"
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm using these xml files as samples (from the examples in [Finnbarr P. Murphy's "XSLT 1.0 Multiple Namespace Issues"](http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2010/10/xslt-multiple-namespaces-in-xml-documents.html))

*sample1.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<emp:root xmlns:emp="http://www.example.com/ns/employee/2006">
    <emp:employee status="Guru">
        <emp:first>John</emp:first>
        <emp:last>Kane</emp:last>
        <emp:department>IT</emp:department>
        <emp:country>IE</emp:country>
    </emp:employee>
</emp:root>
```

*sample2.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<emp:root xmlns:emp="http://www.example.com/ns/employee/2012">
    <emp:employee status="Guru">
        <emp:first>John</emp:first>
        <emp:last>Kane</emp:last>
        <emp:department>IT</emp:department>
        <emp:country>IE</emp:country>
    </emp:employee>
</emp:root>
```

The desired result should be in both cases:

```
First Name "John"
Last Name  "Kane"
Department "IT"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you witness is caused by different namespaces:

- **sample1.xml** defines the `emp` namespace as `"xmlns:emp="http://www.example.com/ns/employee/2006"`
- **sample2.xml** defines the `emp` namespace as `"xmlns:emp="http://www.example.com/ns/employee/2012"`

So in one case your template will fail, because its `<template...>`s rules won't match due to a different *namespace-prefix* (`...2006` != `...2012`).

---

So to create a template which ignores the namespaces, the *namespace-prefixes* have to be ignored.
This is done by only regarding the `local-name()` of the element's names and not the whole names.

For example, a namespace'd element's name may be `emp:first`.
So `name()` would return `emp:first` and `local-name()` would merely return `first`.

Ignoring the namespace-prefix (in this case `emp`) is achieved by only concentrating on the `local-name()` of all relevant elements.

So the following template is constructed by

- Selecting all elements with `*`
- And restricting this set of elements by using a predicate `[local-name() = '...']` which checks for the elements which `local-name()` matches

The whole template looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'employee']">
        First Name "<xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = 'first']" />"
        Last Name  "<xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = 'last']" />
        Department "<xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = 'department']" />"
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and returns the same result for both XML input files.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot bind a prefix to a variable URI.

However, the prefix itself is of no significance - only the URI matters. If you know what the expected namespace URIs are, you can bind each of them to its own prefix and use both, for example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:emp6="http://www.example.com/ns/employee/2006"
xmlns:emp12="http://www.example.com/ns/employee/2012">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="emp6:employee | emp12:employee">
    First Name "<xsl:value-of select="emp6:first | emp12:first"/>"
    Last Name  "<xsl:value-of select="emp6:last | emp12:last" />"
    Department "<xsl:value-of select="emp6:department | emp12:department"/>"
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

The other option is to start by getting the namespace URI from the incoming XML (like you started to do) and use it to generate an XSLT stylesheet where the (constant) prefix is bound to the extracted URI.

Then apply the generated stylesheet to the original XML in order to get the final result.